# using alias in mysql where condition to calculate

Tags: mysql, case, where-clause, case-when

```
select 
    delegation_cycle.delegation_cycle_id as task_id,
    delegation_cycle.delegate_from_id as from_id,
    delegation_cycle.delegate_to_id as to_id,
    delegation_cycle.time_estimate as main_time_estimate,
    delegation_cycle.status as main_task_status,
    delegation_cycle.start_date as main_start_date,
    delegation_cycle.changes,
    DATE(delegation_cycle.delegated_time) as orginal_email_time,
    tasks.task_name,
    tasks.client_id,
    tasks.followup,
    tasks.task_owner,
    tasks.main_due_date,
    tasks.main_priority,
    1 as delegated,
    delegation_user_relation.showinlist,
    users.email as email_from,
    clients.client_name,
    (select 
            count(delegation_cycle_id)
        from
            delegation_cycle
        where
            delegation_cycle.task_id = tasks.task_id
                and delegation_cycle.task_parent = '2') as delegationcount,
    (select 
            sum(status)
        from
            delegation_cycle
        where
            delegation_cycle.task_id = tasks.task_id
                and delegation_cycle.task_parent = '2'
                and delegation_cycle.status = '4') as sumstatus,
    (select 
            count(notes_records_id)
        from
            notes_records
                join
            notes ON notes.notes_id = notes_records.notes_id
        where
            notes_to = '2'
                and notes.task_id = delegation_cycle.task_id) as notescount,
    (select 
            count(notes_records_id)
        from
            notes_records
                join
            notes ON notes.notes_id = notes_records.notes_id
        where
            notes_to = '2'
                and notes.task_id = delegation_cycle.task_id
                and notes_records.read = 0) as unreadnotescount
from
    delegation_cycle
        inner join
    tasks ON tasks.task_id = delegation_cycle.task_id
        inner join
    users ON users.user_id = delegation_cycle.delegate_from_id
        inner join
    clients ON clients.client_id = tasks.client_id
        join
    delegation_user_relation ON delegation_user_relation.delegate_task_id = tasks.task_id
where
    delegation_cycle.delegate_to_id = '2'
        and delegation_cycle.status != 4
        and case
        when
            delegation_cycle.status != 3
        then
            (delegation_user_relation.showinlist = 1
                || delegation_user_relation.showinlist = 2)
                and delegation_user_relation.user_id = '2'

        else delegation_user_relation.user_id = '2'
    end
```

hi have this query running and i would like to check use `delegationcount` and `sumstatus` in where condition with case statement like this

```
 when delegation_cycle.status != 3 && delegationcount*4!=sumstatus then 
(delegation_user_relation.showinlist = 1 || delegation_user_relation.showinlist = 2)  
 and delegation_user_relation.user_id = '2'  else delegation_user_relation.user_id = '2'    
 end
```

i would like to use the alise name in where condition but its not possible for me with this query ,so i would like to reframe this query to use alise name in where condition

Comment: can you try to be clearer, and tell us what issues are you facing? do you see an error?

Comment: I'm not going anywhere near that!

Comment: i would like to use the alise name in where condition but its not possible for me ,so i would like to reframe this query to use alise name in where condition

Comment: For what do you want alias name?

Comment: @G one to use here delegation_cycle.status != 3 && delegationcount*4!=sumstatus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can defined temp session variables in-line with the query and use the same in where clause.

```
select 
    delegation_cycle.delegation_cycle_id as task_id,
    delegation_cycle.delegate_from_id as from_id,
    delegation_cycle.delegate_to_id as to_id,
    delegation_cycle.time_estimate as main_time_estimate,
    delegation_cycle.status as main_task_status,
    delegation_cycle.start_date as main_start_date,
    delegation_cycle.changes,
    DATE(delegation_cycle.delegated_time) as orginal_email_time,
    tasks.task_name,
    tasks.client_id,
    tasks.followup,
    tasks.task_owner,
    tasks.main_due_date,
    tasks.main_priority,
    1 as delegated,
    delegation_user_relation.showinlist,
    users.email as email_from,
    clients.client_name,

    @delegationcount:=(select 
            count(delegation_cycle_id)
        from
            delegation_cycle
        where
            delegation_cycle.task_id = tasks.task_id
                and delegation_cycle.task_parent = '2') as delegationcount,

    @sumstatus:=(select 
            sum(status)
        from
            delegation_cycle
        where
            delegation_cycle.task_id = tasks.task_id
                and delegation_cycle.task_parent = '2'
                and delegation_cycle.status = '4') as sumstatus,

    @notescount:=(select 
            count(notes_records_id)
        from
            notes_records
                join
            notes ON notes.notes_id = notes_records.notes_id
        where
            notes_to = '2'
                and notes.task_id = delegation_cycle.task_id) as notescount,

    @unreadnotescount:=(select 
            count(notes_records_id)
        from
            notes_records
                join
            notes ON notes.notes_id = notes_records.notes_id
        where
            notes_to = '2'
                and notes.task_id = delegation_cycle.task_id
                and notes_records.read = 0) as unreadnotescount
from
    delegation_cycle
        inner join
    tasks ON tasks.task_id = delegation_cycle.task_id
        inner join
    users ON users.user_id = delegation_cycle.delegate_from_id
        inner join
    clients ON clients.client_id = tasks.client_id
        join
    delegation_user_relation ON delegation_user_relation.delegate_task_id = tasks.task_id
where
    delegation_cycle.delegate_to_id = '2'
        and delegation_cycle.status != 4
        and case
        when
            delegation_cycle.status != 3
        then
            (delegation_user_relation.showinlist = 1
                || delegation_user_relation.showinlist = 2)
                and delegation_user_relation.user_id = '2'

        else delegation_user_relation.user_id = '2'
    end
```

And change your new `when ...` clause as below:

```
when 
  delegation_cycle.status != 3 && 
  @delegationcount*4!=@sumstatus then 
    (delegation_user_relation.showinlist = 1 || 
     delegation_user_relation.showinlist = 2
    ) and delegation_user_relation.user_id = '2' 
  else
    delegation_user_relation.user_id = '2'    
end
```

Comment: will this cause any performance issue ,when we have lakhs of records in tables

Comment: 1. Re-calc time comes down, which is good. 2. unless you have indexes on some of the fields, it may affect.